# how to list all the pods who request special resource in k8s like gpu

Tags: gpu, kubectl

GPU is limited resource in my k8s clusters, and I want to locate those pods easily in whole cluster.

```bash
$ kubectl get pods -A -o jsonpath="{.items[*].spec['containers'][*].resources.requests}"
{"cpu":"2","memory":"20Gi","nvidia.com/gpu":"1"} {"cpu":"10m","memory":"40Mi"} {"cpu":"1","memory":"2Gi"}
```

How can I find out the pod list for those resource, for this case `nvidia.com/gpu==1`

I expect to have output like

```
POD     NAMESPACE     GPU RESOURCE
aab     abc           1
aab     abb           2
```

I guess it can be `--field-selector` or `sed/awk`

thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you **can't** do this using `kubectl`'s [JSONPath](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/jsonpath/) because there's no mechanism to capture e.g. `metadata` values (Pod `name`|`namespace`) from the down-scoped filtered value.

You could use any number of tools but, my preference for processing JSON is [`jq`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/) and it has the advantage that, once you learn e.g. `jq`, you can use it everywhere you need to process JSON.

I don't have access to a cluster but I spoofed the JSON output (hopefully correctly) and you should be able to use:

`FILTER=...` (value below)

```
["Pod","Namespace","Container","GPU"],
(
  .items[]
  |.metadata as $metadata
  |.spec.containers[]
  |.resources.requests as $requests
  |select($r|has("nvidia.com/gpu"))
  |[
    $metadata.name,
    $metadata.namespace,
    .name,
    $requests["nvidia.com/gpu"]
   ]
)|@tsv
```

```bash
kubectl get pods \
--all-namespaces \
--output=json \
| jq -r "${FILTER}"
```

###### Explanation

1. We output an array of arrays:

   - the first array is some row headers: `["Pod",...]`
   - the second array is the output of the remaining filter
2. We bind `items[].metadata` to the variable `$metadata`
3. We scope to `items[].spec.containers[]`
4. We then bind `.resources.requests` to `$request`
5. We filter `$requests` by only those containing `nvidia.com/gpu`
6. We then output an array comprising:

   - the `$metadata` variable's `.name` and `.namespace` values
   - the current (`.`) scope's `name` (i.e. the container's name)
   - the `$requests` variable's value of `nvidia.com/gpu`
7. Finally `@tsv` turns an array into a table (tab delimited)

Here's the jq play [snippet](https://jqplay.org/s/xLF2V6XbjJZ)

Comment: very interesting solution with complete explanation!